# Blade Template Layout Structure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-blade

I need to create a row for each 3 attachments. Something like

```
  @foreach($email->attachment as $attach)
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
       <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
       <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>
@endforeach 

   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-4">1st attachment</div>
       <div class="col-lg-4">2nd attachment</div>
       <div class="col-lg-4">3rd attachment</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">4th attachment</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">5th attachment</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">6th attachment</div>
</div>
```

and so on! I had searched for the question but just found  [This link](http://www.example.com/) but It's actually different from my perspective.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use array_chunk](https://www.php.net/array_chunk) - it is designed for this each purpose - so you can cut an array into sub-sizes and loop through each group

```
@foreach (array_chunk($email->attachment->toArray(), 3, true) as $array)
    <div class="row">
    @foreach($array as $attachment)
         <div class="col-lg-4">{{ $attachment['id'] }}</div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

And using @Lukasgeiter's comment - you could also do it this way if it is a [Laravel Collection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/collections)

```
@foreach ($email->attachment->chunk(3) as $array)
    <div class="row">
    @foreach($array as $attachment)
         <div class="col-lg-4">{{ $attachment->id }}</div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: array_chunk requires an array rather an object...??

Comment: Oh yeah. Just convert to an array first. See my updated answer.

Comment: Assuming `$email->attachment` is a Laravel collection you can simply do `$email->attachment->chunk(3)`

Comment: @lukasgeiter - cool - didnt know that. Learn something new every day. I think I need to spend more time looking into the Collections methods.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange You're welcome ;) And yes the collection class has some really nice methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's faster than generate 2 arrays:

```
  <div class="row">
    @foreach( $email->attachment as $index => $attach)
      <div class="col-lg-4">{{$attach}}</div>
      @if( $index+1 === 0)
        </div><div class="row">
      @endif
    @endforeach
  </div>
```